# Dart class StringBuffer string.contains error

Tags: class, dart, contains, stringbuffer

methods ‘contains’ not defined in class ‘stringbuffer’ compilation error is being generated from the following code:

```
import 'dart:math';

var now = new DateTime.now();
Random rnd = new Random();
Random rnd2 = new Random(now.millisecondsSinceEpoch);

void main() {
    int min = 0, max = 255;
    var sb = new StringBuffer();
    int i = 0;

    do {
        var temp = new StringBuffer();
        int r = min + rnd.nextInt(max - min);
        temp.writeCharCode(r);

        if (sb.contains(temp)) {
        }
        else {
            sb.writeCharCode(r);
            i++;
        }
    }
    while (i < 255);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StringBuffer` does not have `contains()` method. You need to build it as `String` first, then call `contains()` to check if it contains a specific char or string.

<sub>Such as StringBuilder in Java, which also needs to convert it into a String before check if it contains something.</sub>